# Is there a way to clean improper shutdown of Raspberry-pi2

Tags: raspberry-pi2

My Raspberry-pi2 keeps corrupting SD card many times. i am tired of changing SD cards. have someone faced the similar problem, if yes then please guide.
As electric supply here is inconsistent so raspberry-pi2 shuts down improperly.
if this is the issue, then whats the solution. please help

Comment: Your SD cards may be (forced) formated, usualy. I don't have a raspberry but have same problem with a notebook without battery, the files are not closed properly. Without a second power source, I don't see how to make the pi2 to get a shutdown signal and die gracefully

Comment: P.S.: add more details. You may format SD in ext3/4, not ext2/FAT; ext3 keep journal for both metadata/files and recover itself at next boot

Comment: @cox i use ext3/4 for formatting. but no luck with this.